# Wordpress mysql query, meta_key value conflict

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query of mysql to a wordpress database, for some reason does not bring me the meta_value of the meta_key "_wp_attached_file", it bring me all others meta_key least that ... 
What can it be, some idea?

Here is the query:

```
`SELECT wposts.* , wpostmeta.meta_value, x.meta_value
    FROM wp_posts wposts, wp_postmeta wpostmeta , wp_postmeta x
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND wposts.ID = x.post_id
    AND x.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'event_date_interval'
    AND STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value,'%Y/%m/%d') >= CURDATE()
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND wposts.post_type = 'event'
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value,'%Y/%m/%d') ASC
    LIMIT 20`
```

Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a typo look @ '_wp_attached_file' should be '_wp_attachment_file'

Rgds,
Florian